# Botón SUBMIT y atributos de reCAPTCHA v3. no funciona, ¿por qué?

Tags: html, recaptcha, contact-form-7

Tengo ya todas las validaciones tanto del lado del cliente como del servidor, para mi formulario de contacto. Ya puse los scripts del head para llamar a las funciones del reCAPTCHA pero tengo un problema con el botón. Tengo el siguiente botón, con algo de Bootstrap e íconos de Fontawesome:

```html
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary d-block upgrade-semibold fs-2" accesskey="S" type="submit" name="submit"><i class="fa-solid fa-microphone text-white" data-fa-transform="left-2"></i> ENVIAR</button>
```

En la página de google developers, en su página de implementación del reCAPTCHA, dice en el punto 3 *AGREGAR atributos a TU botón HTML*. Ellos proponen este código:

```html
<button class="g-recaptcha" 
        data-sitekey="reCAPTCHA_site_key" 
        data-callback='onSubmit' 
        data-action='submit'>Submit</button>
```

Eso me da a entender que puedo usar mi botón personalizado, al cual solamente le AÑADO esos 4 atributos que Google me propone. Entonces la nueva versión de mi botón pasó a esto:

```html
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary d-block upgrade-semibold fs-2 g-recaptcha" accesskey="S" type="submit" name="submit" 
data-sitekey="6Ljdhtr7ywhjrel0okdfh6J...."<!--LO QUE SEA PERO PUSE MI LLAVE PÚBLICA--> 
data-callback='onSubmit' 
data-action='submit'>
<i class="fa-solid fa-microphone text-white" data-fa-transform="left-2"></i> ENVIAR</button>
```

No funciona. No se activa nada, ni siquiera envía, botón muerto como si no existiera, pero sí sale el iconito del recaptcha en la parte inferior derecha. Pero si uso el botón tal como me lo propone Google, solo con esos 4 atributos propios de recaptcha (y nada más), ahí sí funciona algo, al darle clic al botón de ENVIAR puedo ver los mensajes de validación del ¡SERVIDOR! algo que nunca había logrado ver. Estoy trabajando en entorno local, con localhost.

¿Acaso no se puede personalizar un botón solo para que no se vea gris y aburrido? ¿Algo tiene que ver Bootstrap?

Answer (score -1):

Yo precisamente lo configure a través de este tutorial https://netbulbsocialmedia.com/noticias/tutorial-para-configurar-google-recaptcha-v3-ejemplo-en-php/
Te puedo decir que me funciona bien. Lo veo más claro el tutorial que en la página de Google. Yo lo he instalado y me funciona perfectamente.

Hay que diferenciar las dos partes, ya que sino es un poco más engorroso. Por un lado la parte del cliente y por otro la del lado del servidor. La parte del cliente es la más fácil. La parte del servidor copiar el pegar el código y guardarlo con la extension .js posteriormente hacer la llamada al fichero desde el formulario con

```
 <script src="cacha.js"></script>
```

Comment: Acabo de notar que el atributo `name="submit"` es lo que impide que funcione el botón, revisaré lo que me compartes. Gracias.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon un resumen del contenido del enlace. Piensa lo siguiente: si un usuario más adelante encuentra tu respuesta, y el enlace llega a estar roto, ¿cómo podrá constatar si tu respuesta le ha sido útil? Lee [answer].